# Does an IPSEC tunnel establish new sessions for traffic?

Tags: firewall, routing, nat, ipsec, isp

## Background

AT&T business fiber is basically rebranded U-Verse home internet. The "modem" (it's actually a router, but lets call it that for simplicity) has a hard limit of about 8K sessions. Even with the modem in cascading router mode (similar to bridge mode in other devices) the modem still keeps track of TCP sessions and won't allow new ones when the limit is reached. AT&T's answer is basically this problem occurs when a user has outgrown their small business plan and need to move up to enterprise fiber which is several orders of magnitude more expensive for the same speed. This seems silly for a very small office. Considering all the posts I've found around the web about this dating back 3+ years I doubt AT&T is in a hurry to fix it.

Also there are some documented hacks around using a router to bypass the modem but I'm very timid to recommend something flaky to a business. They will need a long term supportable solution. I was surprised at the lack of any discussion around the VPN idea so here I am.

Changing ISPs is being explored, but ISP options are highly limited.

## Questions

If the client provided router downstream of the modem connected to an IPSEC site-to-site VPN tunnel and routed all traffic to the other side of the tunnel would the modem be able to observe multiple sessions? Does the tunnel wrap up all the traffic in it's own established session? Would each new session be a new one out on the WAN just encrypted since IPSEC operates at a higher level than TCP?

## Links to other people describing the issue

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/74qu5s/isp_nat_sessions_limit/

https://medium.com/teamzerolabs/disabling-bypassing-at-t-fiber-nvg595-nat-table-limits-fedora-guide-62d5747e221a

http://solderthoughts.com/2017/06/growing-pains-att-gigabit-fiber/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPsec is a protocol suite, and here we are talking more specifically about *IP Encapsulating Security Payload* (ESP) in *tunnel mode*. The relevant details  are in [RFC 4303, 3.1.2 Tunnel Mode Processing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4303#section-3.1.2):

> In tunnel mode, the "inner" IP header carries the ultimate (IP) source
> and destination addresses, while an "outer" IP header contains the
> addresses of the IPsec "peers", e.g., addresses of security gateways.
>
> - - 
>
> In tunnel mode, ESP protects the entire inner IP packet, including the
> entire inner IP header. - - The following diagram illustrates ESP
> tunnel mode positioning for typical IPv4 and IPv6 packets.
>
> ```
>         -----------------------------------------------------------
>   IPv4  | new IP hdr* |     | orig IP hdr*  |   |    | ESP   | ESP|
>         |(any options)| ESP | (any options) |TCP|Data|Trailer| ICV|
>         -----------------------------------------------------------
>                             |<--------- encryption --------->|
>                       |<------------- integrity ------------>|
>
>         ------------------------------------------------------------
>   IPv6  | new* |new ext |   | orig*|orig ext |   |    | ESP   | ESP|
>         |IP hdr| hdrs*  |ESP|IP hdr| hdrs *  |TCP|Data|Trailer| ICV|
>         ------------------------------------------------------------
>                             |<--------- encryption ---------->|
>                         |<------------ integrity ------------>|
> ```

As, in the tunnel mode, both the original IP headers and *transport layer* headers (not necessarily TCP) are encrypted, the ISP can only see the new IP headers for the IPsec peers and the ESP headers. Therefore, outside the tunnel, it's impossible to tell how many `IP:port` pairs there are on the original headers. (While TCP do have sessions beginning with `SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK` and ending with `FIN, FIN-ACK, ACK`, UDP "sessions" can only be guessed based on the same IP addresses and UDP ports on both ends. Therefore, counting UDP connections as active sessions involves adding artificial connection timeouts.)

However, limiting the amount of concurrent sessions is not the only thing an ISP can do to make you pay more for a connection that is intended for business use. The IPsec VPN tunnel can be detected and blocked. As the outer IP headers (nor the ESP headers) aren't encrypted, e.g. the IP packets having protocol numbers 50 (ESP) or 51 (AH, *Authentication Header*, [RFC 4302](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4302)) could be dropped altogether. The legal side to this would be a *terms of service* stating that site-to-site VPNs aren't allowed.

Comment: There's not a policy against VPN's. In fact there are already 2 site to site connections setup including one to AWS. That was where I got my idea from. 

Thanks for the detailed answer. I was really having a hard time how to frame the question in a way to find the info on my own. 

I think I'm going to ask them for a window and help test it out so we can see how the table in the "modem" reacts. I'll be sure to come back here and let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

> If the client provided router downstream of the modem connected to an
>   IPSEC site-to-site VPN tunnel and routed all traffic to the other side
>   of the tunnel would the modem be able to observe multiple sessions?

No.  All traffic is encrypted between the two IPSec endpoints.  An observer can't see sessions or anything else inside the tunnel.